# Custom notification (Remoteview) not working while app killed

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Custom notification not working when app process killed. App not calling onMessageReceived method when in background/finish.

How to force app to call onMessageReceived(), I just want when I send notification from firebase, it shows my custom notification ...

Here is code ...

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    configs.notificationId = data.get("notificationId");
    configs.title = data.get("title");
    configs.subject = data.get("subject");
    configs.image = data.get("image");

    initwithimage(configs.image);
}

private void initwithimage(String imageUrl) {      
    //Code removed for simplified
    sendwithimage(bitmap);
}

private void sendwithimage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
    contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, bitmap);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, configs.title);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.subject, configs.subject);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.timeago, DateUtils.formatDateTime(getApplicationContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));

    Intent openit = new Intent(this, notificationintentservice.class);
    openit.setAction("openit");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.openit, PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, openit, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Intent closeit = new Intent(this, notificationintentservice.class);
    closeit.setAction("closeit");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeit, PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeit, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "101";

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        //Configure Notification Channel
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Epic Studio");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContent(contentView)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(configs.notificationId), notificationBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {}
```

}

I know firebase not support data type notification, to do that we use notification client like Postman/ARC but I don't know how to use them. I tried Postman and ARC but custom notification still not working.

Here is JSON

```html
{
 "to" : "bLawblawblaw-FeR06mmyABLaBlawblawblawblawblaw",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

I also tried below JSON for send DATA only but not working. Notification not arriving

```html
{
 "to" : "bLawblawblaw-FeR06mmyABLaBlawblawblawblawblaw",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data notification, so first you have to fetch the send notification data then get values inside the data object

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData().get("data");
```

And also add notificationId subject image key in data object others wise notification will not be displayed in notification stack as you will get no key found exception

Comment: Keys are already added I remove some extra code to simplify the question. Thanks alot for giving your time, the problem was @NonNull in onMessageReceived ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was @NonNull at onMessageReceived(**@NonNull** ....)

I was sending data notification in my app through client, so there is no message notification which mean's RemoteMessage is null, that's why method not getting called.